# Error al instalar dependencias dentro de contenedor Docker en node js

Tags: nodejs, docker, dependencias

Tengo el siguiente problema: Quiero automatizar la instalacion de dependencias en el contenedor de mi proyecto con node js pero no pueden instalarse, siempre me aparece que no esta instalada la dependencia mongoose:

Error despues de ejecutar docker compose up api-res-the-liko:
`Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'mongoose' imported from /home/app/src/database/connection.mjs`

Estructura:Asi es como tengo organizados los archivos

```
docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile.dev
├── Dockerfile.prod
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── README.md
├── server.js
└── src
    ├── controller
    │   ├── methods
    │   │   └── methods.js
    │   ├── requests
    │   │   └── productReq.js
    │   └── responses
    │       ├── indexRes.js
    │       └── productsRes.js
    ├── database
    │   └── connection.mjs
    ├── models
    │   ├── Category.js
    │   ├── Combo.js
    │   ├── DrinkMix.js
    │   ├── Product.js
    │   └── Subcategory.js
    ├── routes
    │   ├── index.routes.js
    │   └── products.routes.js
    └── server
        ├── executor.js
        └── settings.js
```

Tengo el siguiente docker file que uso porque preparo un ambiente de produccion

Dockerfile.prod:

```
\`FROM node:20.9.0-alpine3.17

RUN mkdir -p /home/app

WORKDIR /home/app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY  . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD \[ "node", "." \]\`
```

Docker compose:

```
\`version: "3.9"
services:
api-rest-the-liko:
build:
context: .
dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod  
container_name: api-rest-container
image: api-rest-image
ports:
\- "8080:8080"
environment:
\- PORT=8080
\- NODE_ENV=production  
volumes:
\- .:/home/app
\- .:/home/app/node_modules

development-service:
build:
context: .
dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev  
command: \["nodemon", "."\]
container_name: development-container
image: api-rest-image-dev
ports:
\- "8081:8081"
environment:
\- PORT=8081
\- NODE_ENV=development
volumes:
\- .:/home/app

\`
```

package.json:

```
{   "name": "the-liko-api",   "version": "1.0.0",   "description": "",   "type": "module",   "main": "server.js",   "scripts": {     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"   },   "repository": {     "type": "git",     "url": "git+https://github.com/Los-Ferchos/the-liko-api.git"   },   "keywords": [],   "author": "Los Ferchos",   "license": "ISC",   "bugs": {     "url": "https://github.com/Los-Ferchos/the-liko-api/issues"   },   "homepage": "https://github.com/Los-Ferchos/the-liko-api#readme",   "devDependencies": {     "nodemon": "^3.0.1"   },   "dependencies": {     "cors": "^2.8.5",     "dotenv": "^16.3.1",     "express": "^4.18.2",     "nodemon": "^3.0.1",     "mongoose": "^8.0.0"   } }
```

Probe modificar el Dockerfile.prod a como se encuentra ahora y no tengo mas ideas, tambien vi en un foro que compartian el volumen de node_modules y lo probe y tampoco